# Import of data from external web page, export to csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to find a solution to how to export data from a table in an external link to a local CSV file. I would have been very excited if someone could have come with tips and help to find out.

Example of the table can be found here: http://www.rafisklaget.no/portal/pls/portal/PORTAL.LANDINGSPLANNING.show?p_arg_names=p_regmerke&p_arg_values=T%200182T

I would also like to copy content to the empty columns down the table, if there is data in a columns or that the table ends.

This gets a little too complicated for me to figure out, I will spend too much time. Is there anyone who can help me with this? If you had been able to download content from multiple tables in the same operation, it would have been an advantage since I have around 2000 tables to be loaded into Mysql every day :-)

I use this PHP script to download data from the external site as an HTML table. This table is someting that I want to convert to CSV an import into MySQL.

```
    $ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.rafisklaget.no/portal/pls/portal/PORTAL.LANDINGSOPPLYSNING.show?p_arg_names=p_regmerke&p_arg_values=T%200182T');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
file_put_contents("T 0182T.php", $data);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: “This gets a little too complicated for me to figure out, I will spend too much time” – then maybe hire somebody to do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear. But anyhow, let's make a proposal. I won't post you code, because you need to do a little research yourself.
But i will propose some steps for you.

- Connect to your database
- Open file to write
- Repetative steps:
- - SELECT * FROM table
- - fetch results
- - use fputcsv to write the row of the table to your file
- Close database connection
- Close file

If you need a file per table, ofcourse you have to include the write-file open and close within your repetative steps :)

Comment: I have no trouble getting data out or into Mysql, the problem is to get the converted HTML table that I download using the script to CSV so I can import it into MySQL